# How to change the subtotal rounding in sale order

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

With odoo 8 in Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy there is "Account"by default , when i modify the digits to 3 the subtotal rounding changed . But in odoo 9 there is not "Account" by default , and even when i tried to create it there is no change in the subtotal display.Any help please ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default odoo set decimal precision in the object decimal_precision. example, in sales:

```
'amount_untaxed': fields.function(_amount_all_wrapper, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Untaxed Amount')
```

this field get decimal with name is account. you can change the configuration in Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy

Comment: with odoo 8 in Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy there is "Account"by default , when i modify the digits to 3 the subtotal rounding changed . But in odoo 9 there is not "Account" by default , and even when i tried to create it there is no change in the subtotal display. Could you help me please to resolve that problem ?

Comment: im so sorry i dont have odoo-9 but if i try in odoo-10, i create new decimal precision with name 'Account' with digits is 3. and setting rounding factor to change decimal places in currency and make the sales changed.